# PHP project with Google Calendar API

Tags: php, object-oriented, datetime, api

I'm playing with a simple (for now) project in PHP with Google Calendar API. I have posted the code here in order to improve my programming style about whatever you think it's worth suggesting. Thank you.

As you can see, at the moment the script `listEvents.php` retrieves all the events in the last 7 days from `primary` calendar, and deletes the events whose title is included in the array `deletable`.

Below is the code so far:

**listEvents.php**

```
<?php

require_once (__DIR__."/beAuthorized.php");
require_once (__DIR__."/calConfig.php");

$beAuthorized = new beAuthorized();
$calConfig = calConfig::getInstance();

$deletable = $calConfig->getDeletable();
$calendarId = $calConfig->getCalendarId();

$optParams = array(
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', strtotime('-7 days')),
  'timeMax' => date('c'),
);

try {
    $service = $beAuthorized->getService();
    $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
    $events = $results->getItems();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

if (!empty($events)) {
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        if (in_array($event->getSummary(), $deletable)) {
               $service->events->delete($calendarId, $event->getId());
        }
    }
}
```

**beAuthorized.php**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

class beAuthorized
{
     /**
     * Returns an authorized API client.
     * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
     */
    private function getClient()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('calendar-utilities');
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);
        $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

        // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        // time.
        $tokenPath = 'token.json';
        if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        }

        // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            } else {
                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';
                $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }
            // Save the token to a file.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
        return $client;
    }

    /**
    * Returns a service object.
    */
    public function getService() 
    {
        // Get the API client and construct the service object.
        $client = $this->getClient();
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        return $service;
    }
}
```

**calConfig.php**

```
<?php

require_once (__DIR__."/singleton.php");

class calConfig extends singleton
{
    private $calendarId;
    private $deletable;

    protected function __construct()
    {
          if(!isset($this->calendarId)) {
               $this->calendarId = 'primary';
          }

          if(!isset($this->deletable)) {
              $this->deletable = array('Test', 'bye', 'one');
          }
    }

     public function getCalendarId() {
         return $this->calendarId;
     }      

     public function getDeletable() {
          return $this->deletable;
     }
}
```

**singleton.php**

```
<?php

class singleton
{
    private static $instances = [];
    protected function __construct() { }
    protected function __clone() { }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        throw new \Exception("Cannot unserialize singleton");
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        $subclass = static::class;
        if (!isset(self::$instances[$subclass])) {
            self::$instances[$subclass] = new static;
        }
        return self::$instances[$subclass];
    }
}
```